# how to get literal array value stored inside script tag on html page using javascript or protractor

Tags: javascript, arrays, jasmine, protractor

I'm using Protractor, a nodejs based test automation tool with Javascript language for test scripts creation.

I need to get a specific data from HTML page source that have `script`tag that have some **Literal array** stored inside as the followings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var propertypv_obj =[{"listing_id":1545780,"cat":8733,"loc":5687,"purpose":2,"type":4}]
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share some more html code?

Comment: @KishanPatel please see below complete script tag:

<script type="text/javascript"> var propertypv_obj = [{"listing_id":1545780,"cat":8733,"loc":5687,"purpose":2,"type":4}, {"listing_id":7845258,"cat":8732,"loc":5687,"purpose":2,"type":4}</script>

Comment: So what is your test case? What you want to capture from script ?

Comment: I need to capture array as a whole i.e. propertypv_obj 
OR each item individually i.e. listing_id, cat, loc etc. from this script tag.

Comment: @KishanPatel any further feedback?

Comment: Can you provide me some more detail of html code ?

Comment: `//script[contains(.,'1545780')]` Can you try the following xpath.

 `var a = element(by.xpath("//script[contains(.,'1545780')]")).getText().then(function(msg){
       console.log(msg);
     })`

Comment: OR
`var a = element(by.xpath("//script[contains(.,'1545780')]"));
     expect(a.getAttribute("propertypv_obj.listing_id")).toEqual('1545780');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use executeScript to return the data to Protractor:

```
browser.executeScript('return propertypv_obj;').then(function(result) {
    expect(result[0].cat).toEqual(8733);
}
```